# Can I use carnivorous plants to control cockroaches?

Tags: pest-control, indoors, carnivorous-plants

I've started seeing cockroaches in the kitchen at work. We've managed to keep their population from exploding by cleaning. Since their food supply is now limited and the critters are highly active, I expect that they would be quite vulnerable to traps.

The traps I have in mind are carnivorous plants, like [pitcher plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcher_plant). Are there any species that specialize in beetles, or more specifically, cockroaches?

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not going to work. The effort to create an environment for pitcher plants would be huge and cockroaches can survive on barely anything.

Comment: I agree, cockroaches can survive nuclear Armageddon!!  I like your thinking, however!  I'd be shakin' in my shoes to know of a plant that could take care of cockroaches!  Venus Fly Trap is being 'tested' and used for getting our immune systems engaged to battle cancer the normal way...see 'Carnivora'...what do the inspectors of your kitchen recommend?  What you have done is the best action but to fine tune this...need more info.  How about a picture of these insects?

Comment: Not sure if I can catch one on my phone's camera, but they are about 7 to 15 mm long. My coworkers assure me that these are really cockroaches; this is my first encounter with them (I grew up on an island that they have not yet invaded).

Comment: Cats, or similar small insectivores are likely a better choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nice sentiment, but considering practicality, even if you did get the environment right for your plants (most carnivorous plants are rather picky), cockroaches are not going to fall into the traps. They are careful, and usually ground feeders. They will rarely fall from above, and falling into a plant trap is not a likely thing.

Most carnivorous plants target flying insects, and the ones that also target ground feeders are usually too small. Better to go with regular traps.

Answer (score 3):

I purchased a venus flytrap in the middle of my roach erradication. (My ex roomies left their own roomies)
So far, one plant has captured twelve baby roaches that were drawn to the nectar.
Even baby heads of the flytrap have snapped on the tiny bugs.